# How to execute aws ec2 describe-instances for different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Assuming we have two AWS acounts: Account-A, Account-B and an ec2 instance running on AccountA.

`aws ec2 describe-instances` works as expected for the instance's own account without an `~/.aws/credentials` file with an instance role.

My goal is to run `aws ec2 describe-instances` for Account-B from this instance.

The following command works and outputs credentials:

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/accountb-role --role-session-name test
```

However, this does not:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --profile AccountB

'aws_access_key_id'
```

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region = us-east-1

[profile AccountB]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/accountb-role
source_profile = default
```

As I mentioned, `~/.aws/credentials` does not exist as the instance uses an instance role for IAM.

**accountb-role Trust Relationship Policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678900:role/accounta-role"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**instance inline policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1490625590000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/accountb-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both the `accounta-role` instance role and `accountb-role` also have the stock `ReadOnlyAccess` IAM policy attached.

Comment: What is the error message when you try to run the describe-instances with the profile switch?

Comment: `'aws_access_key_id'` is the error message, nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is still interested in the answer, you have to save the aws credentials to be able to use AccountB between these calls:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/accountb-role --role-session-name test
```

<< save aws_access_key_id,  aws_secret_access_key, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN here>>

You then call

```
aws configure --profile AccountB
```

to make sure you have them set up. also, can AWS_SESSION_TOKEN expire after some time

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile AccountB
```

[This article](http://www.systemsup.co.uk/aws-cross-account-deployments-using-sts-assumerole/) explains in detail

Answer (score 0):

In your IAM panel there is also the ability to grant access to a cross-account IAM user, which is what it sounds like you're looking for.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html